# Why didn't The Amazing Spider-Man show Norman Osborn?

Tags: marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

In The Amazing Spider-Man (2012), Norman Osborn is frequently referenced as the reason for employment of Curt Connors/the Lizard, but always represented by a proxy in the form of Oscorp executive Rajit Ratha, played by the late, great Irrfan Khan in one of his first Hollywood roles.

It seems a weird choice to include Osborn as a minor part of the storyline but never show him on-screen - it would seem to make more sense to either make him a major part of the storyline or not to reference him at all. Have the filmmakers ever shed light on why exactly they chose to do this?

Comment: He was seen [on-screen in a picture frame](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/amazingspiderman/images/0/02/Norman_Osborn.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20121026114120) :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably this was to avoid the mistakes of the Sam Rami Spider-Man films.

> Marc Webb's Spidey reboot is trying to avoid overloading the screen with villainy. It was a misstep to which Sam Raimi's Spider-Man 3, host to every bad guy this side of the Hooded Claw and Simon Cowell, fell prey, but one from which Sony will have learnt. - [EmpireOnline 9-11-2013](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/chris-cooper-talks-norman-osborn-spidey-3/)

Chris Cooper, the actor who portrays Norman Osborn in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*, says this:

> "['Amazing Spider-Man 2'] is an introduction to Norman Osborn, and, apparently, this leads to better things in 'Spider-Man 3'. I think it's fair to say that he's on his last legs and I don't know if I can say anything more." - [ScreenRant Sep-11-2013](https://screenrant.com/amazing-spider-man-2-3-norman-osborn-chris-cooper/)